# Multiple Sliding Divs from Animated Menu

Tags: javascript, animation, html, button, slidetoggle

So, the effect I'm going for is:

http://jsfiddle.net/SCKhf/428/

This functions EXACTLY how I want it to. However, I want to replace the simple Linked words with an animated menu.

My coding is currently like:

http://jsfiddle.net/M8UgQ/4/

The divs don't show up! The javascript is the same for calling the div. The only difference in the javascript coding is the addition of the hover animation.

```
var open = $('.open'),
a = $('ul').find('a');

console.log(a.hasClass('active'));

open.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        speed = 500;
    if($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
        $this.removeClass('active').next('.box').slideUp(speed);
    } else if(a.hasClass('active') === false) {
        $this.addClass('active').next('.box').slideDown(speed);
    } else {
        a.removeClass('active').next('.box').slideUp(speed);
        $this.addClass('active').next('.box').delay(speed).slideDown(speed);
    }
});
```

I would greatly appreciate any support here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your HTML made your `next('.box')` function not work.  `next('.box')` finds the next sibling, in this case of the `<a>` tag that was clicked, that matches the selector.  Since the box is no longer a sibling, the function doesn't find any elements.

I've changed `next('.box')` to `.parent().parent().find('.box')` box and it appears to work as desired:  http://jsfiddle.net/M8UgQ/7/

Comment: Tried out what you made. A big leap forward, but the div pages seem to be appearing inside the menu buttons.

Comment: If they're not going to appear inside the menu buttons, why not give each an id and find it by the id like `$('#games')` instead of using `.next()`, `.parent()`, and `.find()`?

Comment: So, give an id to each page? How exactly would I need to change my coding? I know how to assign ids and whatnot. What would the js need to be. How would I format that in the html?

Comment: the divs would have `<div id="some_id_1">`.  The JavaScript selector would be `$('#some_id_1')` if you're using jQuery.  The html would be putting the div wherever you want it to be, that's a style choice and not a coding issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll give you a check and call this answered.

Comment: Hey JSP,I'm still struggling with this. I'm sorry for being so lacking in my skills, but if you could run up a working example, that would be amazing. I have tried to do this myself but it doesn't seem to work. Or I'm positioning everything wrong.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but it only opens one of the "pages". How do I direct each button to a separate div? I have declared pages of #page_Home .box, etc. in the CSS.